# Jetpack Navigation Drawer always recreate fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I tried to use default setup of Jetpack Navigation Drawer generated by AS IDE but I have this problem where it always recreate fragments when switching/navigating instead of just adding a new fragment on the top? They say that it was intended but is there any solution to not recreate fragments even without handling ViewModel stuff?

This is the activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private var _binding: ActivityMainBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreate and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        _binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar)

        drawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout
        val navView: NavigationView = binding.navView
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_marketcap, R.id.nav_about), drawerLayout)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).isChecked = AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES
        return true
    }


    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        _binding = null
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START))
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        else
            super.onBackPressed()
    }

}
```

Fragment

```
class AssetFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = AssetFragment()
    }

    private lateinit var viewModel: AssetViewModel

    private var _binding: FragmentAssetsBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private lateinit var logTxt: AppCompatTextView
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var swipeRefreshLayout: SwipeRefreshLayout

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View {

        _binding = FragmentAssetsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root

        recyclerView = binding.recyclerView
        swipeRefreshLayout = binding.refreshLayout
        logTxt = binding.errorLog

        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        adapter = AssetAdapter(requireContext(), this)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter

        swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = true
        fetchAssets("30")

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener {
            swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = true
            fetchAssets("30")
        }

        return root

    }

    private fun fetchAssets(limit: String) {

        //Network stuff
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(AssetViewModel::class.java)
        // TODO: Use the ViewModel
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

}
```

Navigation xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/nav_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:name=".ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_marketcap"
        android:name=".ui.marketcap.MarketCapFragment"
        android:label="@string/marketCap"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_marketcap" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_about"
        android:name=".ui.about.AboutFragment"
        android:label="@string/about"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_about" />

</navigation>
```

Menu xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item android:title="@string/menu">
            <menu>

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_home"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_crypto"
                    android:title="@string/home" />

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_marketcap"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_marketcap"
                    android:title="@string/marketCap" />

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_about"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_about"
                    android:title="@string/about" />

            </menu>
        </item>

    </group>

        <item android:title="@string/connect">
            <menu>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/email_connect"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_email"
                    android:title="@string/fui_email_hint" />
            </menu>
        </item>

</menu>
```

`onCreateView` is getting called every time a fragment switch even pressing back button. I needed to avoid recreating `Home` fragment, just like when you regularly use fragment manager to add and pop fragment at the top and do not recreate the home fragment.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have same problem.

Comment: @lazy you can use ViewModel to save all data necessary for your views e.g. RecyclerView but remember that fragments are being replace in Jetpack navigation so you still recreating/inflating the view even you just press onBack to resume your user to home/base fragment.

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS Thank you in advance for taking the time to answer me, but unfortunately, viewModel can’t solve my problem. I have a side drawer, and several will navigate to the same web fragment (different url), but every time I click, the fragment will be recreating/inflating,
Webview initialization caused a very poor experience

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#share_ui-related_data_between_destinations_with_viewmodel

> Any ViewModel objects created in this way live until the associated
> NavHost and its ViewModelStore are cleared or until the navigation
> graph is popped from the back stack.

In the fragment,
instead of

```
    private lateinit var viewModel: AssetViewModel
```

put there

```
val viewModel: AssetViewModel
        by navGraphViewModels(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
```

And remove

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(AssetViewModel::class.java)
```